# Copying sheets without copying full data validation address

Tags: excel, vba

If I put a data validation source in workbook `original workbook.xlsm` on `Sheet1` as `"='Validations'!$A$2:$A$10"` using the following VBA:

```
Public Sub AddValidationToRange(targetRng As Range, validRng As Range)
With targetRng.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
        AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, _ 
        Formula1:="='" & validRng.Worksheet.Name & "'!" & validRng.Address
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End Sub
```

And then I copy `Sheet1` to another workbook, the data validation source becomes `"=[original workbook.xlsm]Validations'!$A$2:$A$10"`

I'm also using VBA to copy the sheet:

```
ws.Copy after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.count)
```

I don't want this workbook assumption to happen, I want the source to stay exactly as `"='Validations'!$A$2:$A$10"` because I will be copying the `Validations` sheet to the same new workbook for customisation anyway.

Is there a way I can effectively remove the "absolute" reference to the workbook and keep the data validation local to its host book?

Comment: Maybe using `INDIRECT` but haven't tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Group (Array) of Worksheets

- You can achieve this by copying both worksheets 'in one go'.
- Manually: select `Sheet1` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and select `Validations`. Now right-click on one of those tabs and choose `Move or Copy`...
- You can also use the following code.

**The Code**

```
Sub copyGroupOfWorksheets()
    
    Dim swb As Workbook
    Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook conataining this code.
    Dim dst As Workbook
    Set dst = Workbooks("Test.xlsm")
    
    swb.Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Validations")).Copy _
      After:=dst.Sheets(dst.Sheets.Count)

End Sub
```

Comment: Great stuff, I vaguely remember seeing an array of sheets being used before and this seems like a perfect use case. I'll try tomorrow morning!

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks very much, I'll certainly remember this.